# how to make laravel auto redirect a user when the session has expired

Tags: laravel

I am working on a project using laravel 4.2. I want when the user is logged in their session will expire in 60 mins and laravel will auto redirect the user without them interacting with web application. however, I am not seeing anything in the laravel docs that explains how to do this approach. If you can assist me with this problem that would be much help thanks.

Comment: do you mean the browser should understand the expiration time automatically?

Comment: yea that is what i want

Comment: accept the answer which worked for you or post your own, if you are asking a question it is your responsibility to accept an answer or otherwise post your own.

Answer (score 3):

Well. You should make an AJAX call to the server each minute, and then process the request:

```
setInterval(function(){
     $.get("user/timespan");
}, 6000); // send request each 60 seconds
```

Now in laravel's controller you put:

```
class User extends Controller
{
    public function timespan() // here we receive AJAX request
    { 
       $allowed_time = 60 * 60; // seconds
       $current = time(); // we register current time
       $old_time = Session::get("user_loggedin); // we registered this session when user logged in
       if( ($current - $old_time) > ($allowed_time) )
       {
            // do the redirection, since it has stayed more than 60 minutes
   
        }
    }
}
```

The above solution basically works, but you can set Session time limit to 60 minutes in Laravel, and then send the above ajax request and check for the availability of the session. This saves your life from re-computing the 60-minutes duration.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution of this is using cookies. When you put session, also add cookie then check the cookie.

When logged;

```
Sesion::put("user_data",$user_data);  // or
Auth:attempt($credentials);
Cookie::queue("session_control","value",60);
```

And When you want to check cookie (like on filter);

```
if(!Cookie::has()){
   Session::forget('user_data'); //or
   Auth::logout();
}
```

Comment: i also have the same problem but where can i put the checking of cookie? inside the view?